# Alias, mod_rewrite or something else for shared php scripts?

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias

I have a number of domain names all pointing to the same server and I'm looking for a way to access a set of scripts in a single location from each domain name as a kind of shared resource.

e.g.

```
http://abcdeals.com/shared-resource/
http://defdeals.com/shared-resource/
http://hijdeals.com/shared-resource/
```

all use the same files at /home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource/

---

Full details:

The "shared resource" files reside in the following server path

```
/home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource/
```

The multiple domain names e.g. (abcdeals.com, defdeals.com and hijdeals.com) reside in the following server path

```
/home/abcdeals/public_html/
/home/defdeals/public_html/
/home/hijdeals/public_html/
```

Ideally I would like to be able to access the shared resource files without redirecting the user by accessing

```
http://abcdeals.com/shared-resource/
http://defdeals.com/shared-resource/
http://hijdeals.com/shared-resource/
```

I've been looking at alias and mod_rewrite but to no avail.
Some things I've tried in /home/abcdeals/public_html/.htaccess

```
AliasMatch ^/shared-resource(.*) /home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^shared-resource/(.*) home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource/$1 [L]
```

...and many more similar

I either get a 500 internal server error or 404 not found error when accessing `http://abcdeals.com/shared-resource/`

I also have access to the httpd.conf file if that helps.

The existing .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php [PT]
RewriteRule ^(system/(classes|locale|schema|$)) index.php [PT]
```

I will be eternally grateful for any help on this.

Comment: I have never done this so I'm not sure if this is the right direction... But have you tried using Symbolic links (soft links)?

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll have a look into it

Comment: You should add that as an answer, it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use symlinks for this. In linux you can do this by:

```
ln -s /home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource/ /home/abcdeals/public_html/shared-resource/
```

Which creates a symlink /home/abcdeals/public_html/shared-resource/-->/home/zdeals/public_html/shared-resource/